# Playing a music file before call connects using Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, playback

I have an asterisk server. I use the server to connect an incoming call to another extension based on a few key presses. There is a certain time lag (after the key/extension press and before the call connects). How can I play a small music file (of my choice) in this period? There are some constraints that come to my mind:

1. The music should play only as long as the call does not connect. So, the method used should be a non-locking one.

Any help on this is most welcome.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Could you find any working solution? would appreciate it if you could share it here.

Comment: @Farzan: I was not able to find the exact solution I wanted. Background, as Luc writes, could be a possible solution but for the fact that it is asynchronous. Or you could try Hallman's reply.

Answer (score 2):

Use the m flag to the [Dial](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial) application, to play [music on hold](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+musiconhold.conf) while the call is connecting.

```
exten => 9000,1,Noop
exten => 9000,n,Answer
exten => 9000,n,Dial(SIP/device,0,m)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Background is your friend (http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+BackGround)

Comment: But background would end up returning control while the file is playing. And correct me if I am wrong, but would that not mean that the file could still be playing when the call gets connected?

Comment: I thought it would be a good thing to return control, as you wrote "based on a few keypresses". About the continuation of music, as soon as the Dial is done, the music stops. I mean if A calls your Asterisk server B, it will play music until B has connected to C and put A and C in the same bridge (talking to each other).